# Delay in between reading each chunk of records using Spring batch

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working in a migration project which read data from database, transform each record from the processor, send to the destination webservice and save each record status in a separate status table from the writer. I am using JpaPagingItemReader with a page size of 1000 and a chuck size of 1000. Using spring default DataSource to connect to mysql db. Reader will read the products from the same table based on some product code and for products with small number of records (eg 50k) it is working fine. But I have some products with more than 1 million records and some time after starting I can see a delay in reading next set of records. The delay is getting larger when the time goes up. For eg: until .2 million records the delay is 30 seconds, until .3 its taking 1 min to read the next set of records, and around 8 min for each page read when it reached .8 million records. From the processor and writer logs, I can see that there is no delay. But after finishing that set of records and reading the next set, the delay is showing. Any idea on why this is happening.

Reader Configuration

```
@StepScope
@Bean(name = "TestDataReader", destroyMethod = "")
private JpaPagingItemReader<TestDataEntity> getTestDataJobReader(String productId, String query, JobType jobType) throws Exception {
    JpaNativeQueryProvider<TestDataEntity> queryProvider = new JpaNativeQueryProvider<>();
    queryProvider.setSqlQuery(env.getProperty(query));
    queryProvider.setEntityClass(TestDataEntity.class);
    queryProvider.afterPropertiesSet();
    JpaPagingItemReader<TestDataEntity> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>(){
        @Override
        public int getPage() {
            return 0;
        }
    };
    reader.setEntityManagerFactory(sourceEntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory());
    reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put(PRODUCT_ID, productId.equalsIgnoreCase(ALL) ? Arrays.asList(0) : jobHelper.getLegacyProductIds(productId));
    reader.setParameterValues(parameters); 
    reader.setPageSize(pageSize);
    return reader;
}
```

Processor

```
@Override
public testDataDTO process(testDataEntity testData) throws Exception {
    log.info("Received test data with MEMID {} - ID {}", testData.getMemid(), testData.gettestID());
    testDataMigrationStatus testDataMigrationStatus = gettestDataMigrationStatus(testData);
    testDataDTO testDataDTO = new testDataDTO();
    try {
        validator.validate(testData);
        log.debug("Validation completed successfully for the test data with ID {}",
                testData.gettestID());
        Request request = testMapper.mapRequest(testData);
        testDataDTO.setRequest(request);
        testDataMigrationStatus.setStatus("COMPLETED");
        log.info("Successfully Validated test data with ID {}", testData.getID());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        testDataMigrationStatus = (testDataMigrationStatus) migrationUtil.handleProcessorExceptions(exception,
                testDataMigrationStatus, getStepExecution());
    }
    testDataDTO.settestDataMigrationStatus(testDataMigrationStatus);
    return testDataDTO;
}

private testDataMigrationStatus getTestDataMigrationStatus(testDataEntity testData) {
    testDataMigrationStatus testDataMigrationStatus = testDataMigrationStatusRepository
            .findBytestID(testData.gettestID());
    if (testDataMigrationStatus == null) {
        testDataMigrationStatus = new testDataMigrationStatus();
        testDataMigrationStatus.settestID(testData.gettestID());
        testDataMigrationStatus.setMemberID(testData.getMemid());
    }
    return testDataMigrationStatus;
}
```

In writer, just sending the data to rest service and saving the status

```
    @Override
public void write(List<? extends TestDataDTO> items) throws Exception {

    
    for (TestDataDTO TestDataDTO : items) {
        TestDataMigrationStatus testDataMigrationStatus = TestDataDTO.getTestDataMigrationStatus();
        if (!TestDataMigrationStatus.getStatus().equals(DataMigrationConstants.FAILED)) {
            processItem(TestDataDTO); // service call and dbsave
        } else {
            saveStatusToDB(TestDataMigrationStatus);  // saving to db
        }
    }
```

}

```
private void saveStatusToDB(TestDataMigrationStatus TestDataMigrationStatus) {
    TestDataMigrationStatus
            .setLastUpdated(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd::HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    TestDataMigrationStatus.setStepExecutionId(getStepExecutionId());
    TestDataMigrationStatusRepository.saveAndFlush(TestDataMigrationStatus);
}
```

Comment: `I have some products with more than 1 million records`: Are doing a query for each item in your item processor? Please share your code to be able to help you.

Comment: Why are you overriding `JpaPagingItemReader#getPage` to return 0?